# Using enter key or a value to close the program

Tags: c#

So, far I have the program working, but I dont know how to close it out using the enter key or returning a value thats not a name like (y,n). I havent seen a solution that would write well into my code without giving me bugs so I feel like there might be a formatting error due to my inexperience.

```
    namespace Likes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rollcall = new List<string>();

            while (true)
            {
                    string names = Console.ReadLine();
                    rollcall.Add(names);
                    var number = rollcall.Count;

                    if (number == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" {0} likes your post.", rollcall[0]);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (number == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} likes your post\n Press Enter to Exit", rollcall[0], rollcall[1]);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (number == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, and {2} other likes your post.\n Press Enter to Exit", rollcall[0], rollcall[1], number - 2);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (number >= 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, and {2} others like your post.\n Press Enter to Exit", rollcall[0], rollcall[1], number - 2);
                        continue;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what causes a program to end? All you need to do is get to the end of the Main method and then there is nothing more to do and the program should end.

Comment: Take a look at `Console.ReadKey` https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just wondering, why cases `== 3` and `>= 4` are both needed?

Comment: I was being pedantic about the string for "1 other" and "2 others" and I'm extremely new to coding lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your `string names = Console.ReadLine();` add the following:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(names) || names == "y" /* and so on */ )
{
    break;
}
```

This will exit the infinite looping while method if input is null, or empty string (enter) or `y`.

Comment: @D.Engle accept the correct answer that was helpful, pls

Answer (score 0):

This may be incorrect as per your requirement. But you can certainly try the idea:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rollcall = new List<string>();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter something here. May be a number");
            var names = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(names))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No input captured. Do you want to exit ?. Press enter to exit.");
                if (ConsoleKey.Enter == Console.ReadKey().Key)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            rollcall.Add(names);
            var number = rollcall.Count;

            if (number == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} likes your post.", rollcall[0]);
                continue;
            }
            else if (number == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1} likes your post\n Press Enter to Exit", rollcall[0], rollcall[1]);
                if (ConsoleKey.Enter == Console.ReadKey().Key)
                {
                    break;
                }

                continue;
            }
            else if (number == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, and {2} other likes your post.\n Press Enter to Exit", rollcall[0], rollcall[1], number - 2);
                if (ConsoleKey.Enter == Console.ReadKey().Key)
                {
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            else if (number >= 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, and {2} others like your post.\n Press Enter to Exit", rollcall[0], rollcall[1], number - 2);
                if (ConsoleKey.Enter == Console.ReadKey().Key)
                {
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done !");
    }
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this one too but I went with the code above for now. Thanks for your help.